# Android App Guessing Game Limiting Guesses

Tags: java, android, if-statement, while-loop

Me again

Attempting to limit the number of guesses in my android guessing game but it's struggling with the fact I'm trying to compare two integers when one of them has already been converted to a string :

```
while (userGuess != userNumber && ++attempts < maxAttempts) ;
```

I'm not sure how I can change it.

By the way, I'm aware that as it stands my code will just go straight to the final if statement and every time I press the guess button it will say that I've already had 3 attempts.

Thanks

```
package lab.mad.cct.c3375331task1;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Task1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

        final TextView textResponse = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        final TextView guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);



        // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String randText = "";
                Random randGen = new Random();
                int ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());
                int attempts = 0;
                final int maxAttempts = 3;

                while (userGuess != userNumber && ++attempts < maxAttempts) ;

                if (userNumber >19 ) {
                    guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("You did it!");
                    guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess  again!");
                    guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                    guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }



                if (attempts == maxAttempts)
                    guessText.setText("You have guessed incorrectly three times.  The answer was" + ranNum);

                randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                textResponse.setText("");

                userGuess.setText("");

            }  
        });

    } 



}
```

Comment: What exact error are you getting, can you post that error trace.

Comment: Sure.  It's: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'int'

Comment: you can get String value from EditText then using Integer.parseInt() to compare with your int value.

Answer (score 0):

Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'int'.

As the error says `userGuess` and `userNumber` can't be compared like this because they are different one in `int` and other is `android.widget.EditText`.

You should first use `gettext()` on `userGuess`  and then compare it to `userNumber` either by converting later into `String` or former into `int`.

Try this,

```
 while(userGuess.getText().equals(String.valueOf(ranNum)  && attempts++ < maxAttempts )
```

Also declare `attempts` as global, you are resetting it on every click which is not required. And remove `while loop` if you want to perform 3 clicks. Also remove `userNumber`, there is no need of it.